# Head First Java book battleship game

Tags: java, arraylist

I am reading "Head First Java" book and I came across the problem in chapter 5 with the battleship game (with simple version). I knew that the book's code doesn't work and I tried my self fixing it, but it still didn't work.

So tried to google it and I found some post on this website but I still have a problem. The game isn't working properly as it should.

If a player enters any random number, the output is always "hit"...

This is the last version of the code:

DotCom class:

```
public class DotCom {

    private ArrayList<String> locationCells = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setlocationCells(int[] loc) {
        if (loc != null)
            for (int val : loc)
                locationCells.add(String.valueOf(val));
    }

    public String checkYourself(String userInput) {

        String result = "miss";
        int index = locationCells.indexOf(userInput);

        if (index >= 0) {
            locationCells.remove(index);
        }

        if (locationCells.isEmpty()) {
            result = "kill";
        } else {
            result = "hit";
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

DotComGame class:

```
public class DotComGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int guessingTimes = 0;
        DotCom dot = new DotCom();
        GameHelperrr helper = new GameHelperrr();

        int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

        int[] locations = { randomNum, randomNum + 1, randomNum + 2 };

        dot.setlocationCells(locations);

        boolean isAlive = true;

        while (isAlive == true) {

            String guess = helper.getUserInput("Enter a number");
            String result = dot.checkYourself(guess);
            guessingTimes++;

            if (result.equals("kill")) {
                isAlive = false;
                System.out.println("You took " + guessingTimes + " guesses");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate to get a detailed and understandable answer, because I'm stuck and I couldn't move on with the book for a few days now.

Comment: What edition of "Head First Java"?  That's a rather old book.  Be careful if it isn't assuming JDK 8 or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int index = locationCells.indexOf(userInput);`

This method will return `-1` if the element doesn't exist in the collection.

So if you miss, it won't hit this condition:

```
if (index >= 0) {
   locationCells.remove(index);
}
```

There are still elements in this collection because you didn't remove anything...

```
if (locationCells.isEmpty()) {
    result = "kill";
} else {
    result = "hit";
}
```

So on a miss, the result still shows "hit."

Try this instead:

```
if (locationCells.isEmpty()) {
   result = "kill";
} else {
   result = index == -1 ? "miss" : "hit";
}
```

**If you haven't killed the opponents ships, then you either miss all ships or you hit a single ship.**

Comment: thanks very much, but could you explain the syntax of "result = index == -1 ? "miss" : "hit"; "  how it works, what it does, because i dont undestand

Comment: It is essentially saying if index is -1 then result should be "miss." Otherwise it is "hit." Research the `ternary operator`: https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the checkYourself-Method must be like this:

```
public String checkYourself(String userInput) {

    String result = "miss";

    int index = locationCells.indexOf(userInput);

    if(index >= 0) {
        locationCells.remove(index);
        if (locationCells.isEmpty()) {
            result = "kill";
        }else {
            result = "hit";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);

    return result;
}
```

In it's current form the ArrayList is never empty because you insert 3 Values but only remove 1 if the user-input is in the list so .isEmpty() is never TRUE.